# JSONModel - Assign value of JSONModel property using other properties in same JSONModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

Here's my JSON data

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name":"Soup",
    "price1":100,
    "price2":10,
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name":"Salad",
    "price1":100,
    "price2":10,
}]
```

I created JSONModel as follows

```
@interface ProductModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float price1;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float price2;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isOK;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float<Optional> total; // not coming
@end
```

In viewcontroller

```
NSArray* models = [ProductModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:objects];
```

Now what I want is

```
if(isOK)
{
   total = price1 + price2;
} else {
   total = price1 - price2;
}
```

Is it possible to write this logic somewhere within the model file, without iterating the model array in viewcontroller and assigning the value of ***total***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is that you create a getter for the `total` property in your `ProductModel` class.

```
-(float) total
{
   if(self.isOK)
   {
      return self.price1 + self.price2;
   } else {
      return self.price1 - self.price2;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Declare a read-only property in `ProductModel`

  ```
  @property (assign, nonatomic, readonly) float total;
  ```
- And implement it

  ```
  - (float)total
  {
     return (self.isOK) ? self.price1 + self.price2 : self.price1 - self.price2;
  }
  ```

Then you can read the value simply with the syntax `model.total`